# Generate random elements from array having hindi characters

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I am trying to develop a program using c++ that generates a random element from an array that has Hindi characters stored in it. I had hardcoded the array while initiating it e.g

```
std::string hindi_array[] = {std::to_string('ठ')};
```

now to generate a random element from the array, I have written a function that generates a random index of the array(which works fine). After I get the random index, I pass it on to another function that uses this index to print the character. The following lines are the snippet for that:

```
   int key = generate_random();
   sprintf(str, "%s", Hindi_array[key].c_str());
   lbl->setCaption(Rand_array[key].c_str());
```

`lbl` is a defined label here. The output that I'm getting is a number like 14722230. Are hindi characters somehow represented in this way at some level? Is there a way to transform it to the actual character that I want to display?

I am a complete newbie to c++ programming so please pardon me if it is too basic or stupid a question. Any help would be great...Thanks!

Comment: That's my mistake sorry..I forgot to change the name of the second array while making the code more comprehensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simple and fast suggestion:
Write a single wide char string with all the letters. I used English letters for clarity.

```
const std::wstring letters = L"ABCDE...";
const size_t letters_count = letters.length(); // or use a macro

// random letter
size_t r = rand() % letters_count;
wchar_t random_letter = letters[r];
```

Comment: Hi egur, I am trying to print the value of random_letter using LOGI in Ubuntu 15.04. 
#define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))

However my application stops there. It simply doesn't print. Is there a way to print it using LOGI. I can't use wcout in this scenario.